# How to displaying the datas in Yii2 index like cardview

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to displaying the datas (for example: `projects` table) in my Yii2 advanced project and i just need to know how can display these things **in my index?**

i mean, i couldn't find any tutorial or discussion about this in the internet.

but with one diffrence, i know we can use `DetailView::widget` or `Gridview widget` or something like that, but, where should i put those codes into it?

i mean, how can use these widgets for each item like a cardview.
exactly like below:

https://play.google.com/store

as you can see, each item has a cardview and another things.

But, how we can use these widgets in index and showing those datas like `cardview`?

Any help i'll appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way with gridview is based on a `raw` result management of callback function for the value

Given a gridview  you can cofigure with proper html each cell

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'yuor_attibute', // you can use a dummy attribute in this case
            'label' => 'your label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {                      
                return "<a href='./yourPath/view?id=". $model->your_column ."'  class = 'btn  btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-user ' > </a>";
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:80px; text-align: center;'],
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'yuor_attibute', // you can use a dummy attribute in this case
            'label' => 'your  2 label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {                      
                return "<img src='./yourPath/image.jpg">";
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:400; height 400 px;'],
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'yuor_attibute', // you can use a dummy attribute in this case
            'label' => 'your  3 label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {                      
                return "< ****the html you prefer ***>";
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:400; height 400 px;'],
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],
       .......
       ......
```

In this way you can easy build the grdiview/table with the content you prefer based on value related to you model or not.

Comment: tnx, but i'm still confusing about using these codes in my index,the thing is, where should i put these codes? which path. it's so hard to find a good solution for these simple things in this framework.

Comment: Yes this is complex, but is related to your request. With Yii2 you can configure the result for gridview in very interssting way.

Comment: Well this code si for a gridview and for the column for a gridview. For each column you can assign the html you prefer for render the table /card your prefer.

Comment: is there any example (project) for using it in yii2 at github or somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know, this is just a tips.. But for the  plaustore sample you show. 
perhaps it is easiest to use a regular grid bootstrap and enter the html code directly in div.

Comment: That's the problem, there is no good tutorial about these things for developing an application, btw, i'll accept this as the best answer.thanks anyway.