# Using another views GridView on Index(or another view) in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, css, gridview, yii2

I'm trying to get the datas from a table which those datas are using by another view and i was wondering if i could show them in my `Yii2 Index` page view like each item with a cardview and details.

Exactly like my previous answer about that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33847647/4960200

Is this possible?

Where or how can I use the datas from that table in my `Yii2 index`?

Or honestly, I couldn't do that in my `views/site/index.php` like this:

```php
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px; background-color: white">
    <div class="row">
        <a class="btn btn-raised btn-sm btn-success pull-right" style="margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 20px">MORE</a>

        <h3 style="margin-left: 20px">Something</h3>

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'yuor_attibute', // you can use a dummy attribute in this case
            'label' => 'your label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return "<a href='./yourPath/view?id=". $model->your_column ."'  class = 'btn  btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-user ' > </a>";
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:80px; text-align: center;'],
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'yuor_attibute', // you can use a dummy attribute in this case
            'label' => 'your  2 label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return "<img src='./yourPath/image.jpg">";
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:400; height 400 px;'],
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'yuor_attibute', // you can use a dummy attribute in this case
            'label' => 'your  3 label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {                      
                return "< ****the html you prefer ***>";
            },
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:400; height 400 px;'],
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
        ],

        </div>
    </div>
```

What should I learn about using this in my index and showing those datas from a table in index?

Comment: Hi @TheGuy.  I think the gridview Index like widget is not the right way for your cardview schema. If you want i can try to propose an approach base on a simple bootstrap  schema.. but only if you are interested

Comment: Please show me your controller and your related model ( Card i guess)

Comment: As I waited I put down a draft, it is a simple loop that uses bootstrap. creates a row for up to 4 cards and inserts a div width a quarter of the page (col-md-3) that contains an image and a title taken by the data provided for the paper

Comment: The controller where you call action  for render this view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample i suppose that the cards are all contained in the dataProvider `$dataProvider->models` and for each model contain an image and a title

this could be the index.php for views/project

```
    <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;



    // title and breadcrumbs not for the moment

    ?>
    <div class="project-index">

        <h2>CARD INDEX TITLE</h2>
        <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

     <?php

$nCardXRow = 4;
$cnt = 0;
echo "<div class='row'>"; // open a new row of 4 card
foreach ($dataProvider->models as $card) {
    echo "div class='card-container col-md-3'><div><img src='" . $card->header.jpg . "'></div><div>" . $card->title . "</div></div>";
    $cnt++;
    if ($cnt == $nCardXRow) {
        echo "</div><!-- close row -->";
        echo "<div class='row'>";  // open a new row
        $cnt = 0;
    }
    echo "</div><!-- close row last row-->";
  }
?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Show me the controller (where you call the render of the view and we can go to result).. Try to understand what we are trying to do, is not difficult..

Comment: How many are the card you want show ? and you want show all the card in a page (for start is better) ?

Comment: I have update the answer using models inside the dataProvider for your index.php

Comment: I' am not at my desk, now i can't chat.. The code provided show something , error?...

Comment: Yes there is a mistake, i forgot to remove the ref to model. I have update the asnwer ... try if there are  other error please..

Comment: Yes a minus instead of a dot.. ok i have update the answer.

Comment: Yes, i had think you have the image addres in the card model, you provide the correct address..

Comment: Where you have save the name of the image. in the Project model? show me the Project model and a name of image for sample.. please. But if you don't know PHP whyyou are doing this...i?

Comment: The project image is the logo?

Comment: Is a full path or a relative path?

Comment: Show me a sample fo the content of this field

Comment: Show the Persons controller.  $dataProvider for ActionIndex should be alreday defined but i need a check

Comment: dataProvider is correctly defined in actionIndex and the should be available in the view. Are you sure for the error.Show me all the error message .

Comment: Try refer to $card->project_title  instead of $card->title

Comment: The error is from site/index show me your site Controller

Comment: Exactly in your Site Controller you do nothing only render a view without dataProvider. Whit which data (image, title) you want populate the view. Where I can obtain these data for rendering by the view?

Comment: Are the card static data not related to db?

Comment: I must go out x a couple of  hours. i comment when cameback

Comment: no problem, thanks for your time, i'll think about it- but the cards will rendered from db - which means, the datas will be shown in 4 card but, from a table and used by two view

Comment: Well, if the data are used by two view is not a problem. but the data to display are form project db table?

Comment: it's working now, after defining in `actionIndex`.thanks for your time